I want to exclude a model property while including its other property
public class Model1 
{
    //other properties
    [InverseProperty("Model1")]
    public virtual ICollection<Model2> Model2 { get; set; } = new List<Model2>();
}

public class Model2 
{
    public int Model1Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Model1Id ")]
    [InverseProperty("Model2")]
    public virtual Model1 Model1 { get; set; }
}

I have these two models and properties as shown here. The issue is that I am getting response like this:
{
    //model1 props
    model2:{
            //model2 props
            model1:{
                    //model1 props
                     ........
                    }
            }
    }
}

Nested like this
return await _context.Model1
                     .Include(x => x.model2)
                     .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

I want to exclude the model1 result from the model2 only in this one query.
I expect an approach to do so with maintaining the code readability and I can not select many columns as I have 28 columns here need to be selected. I can not use LINQ.

Try AsNotracking. Anyway, it is bad practice to expose Model to API. Use DTO and Select or Automapper's ProjectTo.

You use EF, but "I can not use LINQ"? Technically, that can't be true. What do you mean?

I mean I cant use LINQ queries everywhere in my project it will reduce the performance that's why I can't use LINQ. I need a method which I can use everywhere.

https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#explicit-expansion

I have two entities product and category with one-many relationship
public class Product
{
  public int ProductId { get; set; } 
  public string ProductName { get; set; } = null!;
  public decimal? Cost { get; set; }
  public short? Stock { get; set; }
  public bool Discontinued { get; set; }
  public int CategoryId { get; set; }
  public virtual Category Category { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class Category
{
  public int CategoryId { get; set; } 
  public string CategoryName { get; set; } = null!;
  public string? Description { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

then i added my configuration to Category entity using 'AutoMapper'
public static class CartToSummaryMapper
{
  public static MapperConfiguration GetMapperConfiguration()
  {
    MapperConfiguration config = new(cfg =>
    {
      cfg.Internal().MethodMappingEnabled = false;

        cfg.CreateMap<Category, Category>()
         .ForMember(dest => dest.Products, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
            src.Products.Select(x => new Product { 
                Cost = x.Cost,
                ProductName = x.ProductName,
                Discontinued=x.Discontinued,
                ProductId=x.ProductId,
                Stock=x.Stock 
            })));
        
    });
    return config;
  }
}

finally add statment to get your data using EF with 'include' and 'select' like that
MapperConfiguration config = CartToSummaryMapper.GetMapperConfiguration();

IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
categories = db.Categories?
    .Include(category=>category.Products)
    .Select(category => mapper.Map<Category>(category))
    .ToList();

this will prevent EF from reference loop
